# return type of psycopg2 json field is dict on one machine but str on another

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using the python package psycopg2 to get some data from a Postgres db.
My python version is 2.7 and postgres 9.4.

The result of my SQL request has one row and one column, and the result is a string representing a JSON formatted data.

Now I execute the following code:

```
cur.execute(""" my SQL request""")
rows = cur.fetchall()
print type(rows[0][0])
```

On my PC, I get a **dictionary**, meaning that the SQL result is directly loaded as such.
I run the same code on a remote server and I get a **string** as a result. If I want a dictionary I have to additionally write:

```
myDict = json.loads(rows[0][0])
```

Both my PC and the server are running python 2.7 (but not exactly the same 2.7 though) , so I'm a bit confused by this difference in behavior.

Any insight ?

Comment: Are you running the same version of psycopg on both server and laptop? See this: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#json-adaptation